# Polymer 2: letting 2 elements talk to each other through mixin

Tags: polymer, mixins, web-component

I'm trying to build an application where the state of some elements depends on actions in others. Also, these elements have some common properties and methods, which I suppose should be handled with mixins. Unfortunately, it seems that I'm unable to let the mixed-in property change trigger a method in another method.

Some background: this is to build a data visualization app where different views on the same data (hence a "data" property in a mixin) is handled in different elements, and selecting some points in one should highlight the same points in the other plots. I suppose that two-way binding plays a role, but I just can't get it to work... So any help very much appreciated.
Or are there better ways to share data and datasets between elements?

I've assembled a minimalist example just using console log to illustrate the issue. The code below consists of:

- index.html: calls the general polymer app
- polymer-test-app: calls two different custom elements
- my-element-one: Shows the text "Click me", which triggers a change in a property that is defined in the mixin
- my-element-two: Should print the new property value to console every time the text in custom-element-one is clicked (BUT IT DOESN'T)
- my-mixin: Defines the shared property and which method it should trigger

So clicking the text "I am element 1. Click me" in my-element-one should trigger a change in "myvalue" which should call "_shout" in my-element-two

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="/src/polymer-test-app/polymer-test-app.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/src/my-element-one/my-element-one.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/src/my-element-two/my-element-two.html">
    <script src="/src/my-mixin/my-mixin.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <polymer-test-app></polymer-test-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**polymer-test-app**

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="polymer-test-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <h4>Polymer test app</h4>
    <my-element-one myvalue={{mv}}>Test element 1</my-element-one><br/>
    <my-element-two myvalue={{mv}}>Test element 2</my-element-two>
  </template>

  <script>
    class PolymerTestApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'polymer-test-app'; }
    }

    window.customElements.define(PolymerTestApp.is, PolymerTestApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**my-element-one**

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<script src="/src/my-mixin/my-mixin.js"></script>

<dom-module id="my-element-one">
  <template>
    In template of my-element-one<br/>
    <div on-click="handleClick">I am element 1. Click me</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyElementOne extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-element-one'; }

      ready() {
        super.ready()
        this.myvalue = 1
      }

      handleClick() {
        this.myvalue = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
        console.log(this.myvalue)
      }

    }

    window.customElements.define(MyElementOne.is, MyElementOne);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**my-element-two.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<script src="/src/my-mixin/my-mixin.js"></script>

<dom-module id="my-element-two">
  <template>
    In template of my-element-two
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyElementTwo extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-element-two'; }

      _shout() {
        console.log("Value changed: " + this.myvalue)
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyElementTwo.is, MyElementTwo);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**my-mixin.js**

```
MyMixin = function(superClass) {
  return class extends superClass {
    static get properties() {
      return {
        "myvalue": {
          "type": "Number",
          "value": 0,
          "notify": true,
          "observer": '_shout'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: defining `mv` property inside `polymer-test-app` should be enough. Set observer on that `mv` property to call some function which you define in `polymer-test-app` and inside this function you can call function `_shout` inside `my-element-two` with parameter which represents value of `myvalue` property (you get this value as parameter in function that was called by observer). It seems like you didn't understand mixins and how they work. I am not using Polymer 2.0 but try my solution and if you need more help i will explain more

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll give that a try. However, I don't know how to call the `_shout` function from `my-element-two` from within `polymer-test-app`. Can you tell me how to do that? Moreover, in my final app, there will be several (5-10) different custom elements each with their own `_shout` implementation. Would your solution still work?

Comment: and I assume, that you will need to update all of them when 1 input changes? If so, then you will have to, for example, set class `shout` to all elements you will want to update and then in JS, find all elements with class `shout` and call `_shout` function inside it. Back to your question, how to call function inside custom element: just do `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('my-element-two')._shout(someValue)`. This works, if you are using shadow dom. Which I assume you do. you can change selector to whatever you want